# Django: convert QuerySet with related objects to JSON

Tags: python, django, json, django-models, django-queryset

Let's suppose I have two simple Models:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateField()
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place)
```

What I want to do now is query a set of events with the resolved place, and convert everything to a list of dicts, that can be converted to JSON later on.

This is how the end result should look like:

```
[{
   "name": "event1",
   "date": "date1",
   "place": {
       "name": "place1",
       "address": "address1",
   },
},{
   "name": "event2",
   "date": "date2",
   "place": {
       "name": "place2",
       "address": "address2",
   },
},]
```

So far I tried my luck with `ValueQuerySet` and the `.values()` method:

```
Event.objects.all().select_related("place").values()
```

This however won't work, since `.values()` only returns the ids of related objects and not the content. So I was wondering if there is another built-in way to do this kind of conversion or if I have to iterate the QuerySet object and do the conversion by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no default way to create the nested dicts you're after, but you can select the values of related items:

```
# No need for select_related in this case
Event.objects.values('name', 'date', 'place__name', 'place__address')

[{
   "name": "event1",
   "date": "date1",
   "place__name": "place1",
   "place__address": "address1",
},{
   "name": "event2",
   "date": "date2",
   "place__name": "place2",
   "place__address": "address2",
}]
```

If absolutely necessary, you can do some post-processing in Python to get the nested dicts you want.

Comment: This works perfect, thanks a lot. One follow-up question though: Lets say the event model has a One-To-Many relationship with another model "Ad". So, one event can have multiple instances of Ad, that it relates to. Is there also a way I can express such a relationship with `.value()`, so I end up with a list inside of my dict?

Comment: @basilikum No, `values()` will create a dict for every unique combination, so if an Event has a relation with two Ad objects, the Event will be returned twice, once with each Ad object.

Answer (score 2):

There is a relevant method called `model_to_dict`:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
model_to_dict(instance, fields=[], exclude=[])
```

but it won't create dict fields from related models.

Here's the snippets you can use:

- http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2342/
- http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2670/

Hope that helps.